# Find the user who submitted a yarn application using the Java API

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I need to get the details of the user who submitted the Yarn application in the cluster using Java.

I can view those details from the CLI using

```
yarn application -list
```

It gives the list of job details which has the user details.

Now, the requirement is to find the user who submitted the current running job and authorize him before accessing certain files in the cluster. How do I go about doing it? Any valid inputs are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In case of `yarn application` the `yarn` script uses `org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.cli.ApplicationCLI`, so get the source code (in my case it's org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-client:2.7.0)
- Within `ApplicationCLI`, there is a method `listApplications`, and you can extract the user from this:

```java
List<ApplicationReport> appsReport = client.getApplications(appTypes,
    appStates);
```

- So one way is to make a copy of `ApplicationCLI`, and strip off all parts you don't need.

---

As for getting the application ID from "within" a job, there is `SparkContext.applicationId`

Comment: Thanks you but How do we find the application id from the application itself?

Comment: Do you mean the application ID from "within" a job? There is `SparkContext.applicationId`. As for from the "outside": there is `ApplicationReport.getApplicationId()`.

Comment: Yes, it is from the application itself.From what you have provided in your answer I inferred that we can get submitted user name by using application Id details in the list of yarn apps. I am trying my POC on apache Spark and Apache Apex. Hence wondering if there is way we can retrieve the current job id using Yarn or Hadoop_Username rather than SparkContext.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, we can get the username who submitted a job like this:

```
job.getConfiguration().get(MRJobConfig.USER_NAME);
```